# Convertir decimal (google sheet) a hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente decimal `"3,91201611110591"` que equivale a `"93:58:34"` según formato duración en `Google Sheet`.

Necesito transformar ese numero decimal en esa duración con `Javascript`.

Probé:

```
var decimalTimeString = "3,91201611110591";
var decimalTime = parseFloat(decimalTimeString);
decimalTime = decimalTime * 60 * 60;
var hours = Math.floor((decimalTime / (60 * 60)));
decimalTime = decimalTime - (hours * 60 * 60);
var minutes = Math.floor((decimalTime / 60));
decimalTime = decimalTime - (minutes * 60);
var seconds = Math.round(decimalTime);
if(hours < 10)
{
    hours = "0" + hours;
}
if(minutes < 10)
{
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if(seconds < 10)
{
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
alert("" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

pero me arroja otra duración "03:00:00"

También probé

```
var decimalTimeString = "3,91201611110591";
var n = new Date(0,0);
n.setSeconds(+decimalTimeString * 60 * 60);
alert(n.toTimeString().slice(0, 8));
```

Pero tampoco me funciono.

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar de dónde sale el decimal y cómo lo has conseguido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tomamos el valor `3,91201611110591`, lo pegamos en `Google Sheets` y lo formateamos a `duración`, obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **OBSERVACIÓN:** El valor resultante es distinto del publicado en la pregunta.

#### Solución:

Para transformar el decimal al formato duración, puedes hacerlo así:

```js
// Para corregir el formato decimal, reemplazamos la coma por punto
var decimalTimeString = "3,91201611110591".replace(',', '.');
// Convertimos la cadena a decimal
var decimalTime = parseFloat(decimalTimeString);

var hours = Math.floor(decimalTime * 24);
var minutes = Math.floor(decimalTime * 24 * 60) % 60;
var seconds = Math.round(decimalTime * 24 * 60 * 60) % 60;

if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;

console.log(`${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`);
```

Comment: Perfecto Marcos muchas gracias!